# CloudFormation::Init fails to download S3 file with Access Denied

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-cloudformation, amazon-iam, windows-server-2022

I'm trying to download a file from an S3 bucket onto a EC2 Windows server. I'm set up the IAM role, policy, and profile. In the CloudFormation::Init section of the server, I have different configSets and one of them is downloading a file from the bucket.

```
--- Some items not shown ---
"Parameters": {
        "S3BucketName": {
            "Description": "The name of an existing S3 bucket that the server needs to access.",
            "Type": "String",
            "Default": "ccw-to-rds-poc-1"
        },
--- Some parameters not shown ---
"InstanceRole":{
         "Type":"AWS::IAM::Role",
         "Properties":{
            "AssumeRolePolicyDocument":{
               "Statement":[
                  {
                     "Effect":"Allow",
                     "Principal":{
                        "Service":[
                           "ec2.amazonaws.com"
                        ]
                     },
                     "Action":[
                        "sts:AssumeRole"
                     ]
                  }
               ]
            },
            "Path":"/"
         }
      },
      "RolePolicies":{
         "Type":"AWS::IAM::Policy",
         "Properties":{
            "PolicyName":"S3Download",
            "PolicyDocument":{
               "Statement":[
                  {
                     "Action":[
                        "s3:GetObject"
                     ],
                     "Effect":"Allow",
                     "Resource": {"Fn::Join": ["", ["arn:aws:s3:::", {"Ref": "S3BucketName"}]]}
                  }
               ]
            },
            "Roles":[
               {
                  "Ref":"InstanceRole"
               }
            ]
         }
      },
      "InstanceProfile":{
         "Type":"AWS::IAM::InstanceProfile",
         "Properties":{
            "Path":"/",
            "Roles":[
               {
                  "Ref":"InstanceRole"
               }
            ]
         }
      },
      "myAppServer": {
        "Type": "AWS::EC2::Instance",
        "Metadata": {
            "AWS::CloudFormation::Authentication": {
                "S3AccessCreds": {
                    "type": "S3",
                    "roleName": {
                        "Ref": "InstanceRole"
                    },
                    "buckets" : [{"Ref": "S3BucketName"}]
                }
            },
            "AWS::CloudFormation::Init": {
                "configSets": {
                    "downloadS3Data": ["downloadS3"],
                    "Full": [{"ConfigSet": "downloadS3Data"}, "fullServer"],
                    "default": [ {"ConfigSet": "Full"}],
                    "App": [{"ConfigSet": "downloadS3Data"}, "appServer"],
                    "Interface": [{"ConfigSet": "downloadS3Data"}, "interfaceServer"],
                    "Notification": [{"ConfigSet": "downloadS3Data"}, "notificationServer"]
                },
                "downloadS3": {
                    "files": {
                        "C:\\Users\\Administrator\\Documents\\s3download.bak": {
                            "source": "https://ccw-to-rds-poc-1.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/test.txt",
                            "authentication": "S3AccessCreds"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "fullServer": {
                    "commands": {
                        "test": {
                            "command": "echo \"$MAGIC\"",
                            "env": {"MAGIC": "I am from the full server env"},
                            "cwd": "C:\\Users\\Administrator\\Desktop"
                        }
                    }
                },
                --- Some config sets not shown ---
            }
        },
        "Properties": {
            "IamInstanceProfile": {
                "Ref": "InstanceProfile"
            },
            "ImageId": "ami-012bb86d0081c5240",
            "InstanceType": "t2.small",
            "KeyName": {"Ref": "keypair"},
            "SecurityGroupIds": ["sg-0d0b50ca1774707b7"],
            "UserData" : {
                "Fn::Base64" : {
                    "Fn::Join" : [
                        "",
                        [
                            "<powershell>\n",
                                "cfn-init.exe -v -s ", {"Ref" : "AWS::StackId"}, " -r YourInstance -c ", {"Ref": "CCWServerType"} , " --region ", {"Ref" : "AWS::Region"}, "\n",
                            "</powershell>\n",
                            "<persist>true</persist>"
                        ]
                    ]
                }
            }

        }
    }
```

When the server runs `"cfn-init.exe -v -s ", {"Ref" : "AWS::StackId"}, " -r YourInstance -c ", {"Ref": "CCWServerType"} , " --region ", {"Ref" : "AWS::Region"}, "\n",`,

It creates the `s3download.bak`, but it is empty and gives an Access Denied, (HTTP Error 403). Is there something I'm not doing correctly with the IAM configurations that is causing this?

EDIT:
I thought that because I am accessing the entire bucket and not just a specific item, like mentioned in [this article](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/devops/authenticated-file-downloads-with-cloudformation/) that might be the issue. However, after trying `"Action":["s3:*Object"]` and `"Action":["s3.Get*"]`, I still get the same access denied error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is with my IAM policy. I specified the bucket ARN as the resource for the `s3:GetObject` action, but for this action the resource needs to be an object(s). [See AWS S3 Docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/s3-arn-format.html#s3-arn-examples)

So I ended up adding to the end of my S3 ARN with a wildcard so I can get any object in the bucket.

`"Resource": {"Fn::Join": ["", ["arn:aws:s3:::", {"Ref": "S3BucketName"}, "/*"]]}`